Change the crs of a raster to match the crs of a simple feature point object
Say I have a MODIS LAI raster and a simple feature (sf) object (points) with two different crs. I need to transform the crs of the raster to match the crs of the sf data (vice versa would also be ok, but I’d prefer to get rid of the MODIS sinusoidal system). Various attempts did not get me to the solution, i.e., having the raster and sf in the same CRS for further visualization, processing, etcetera. Any help on how can I do this, please? Below are a few options I tried:
library(terra)
library(sf)

lai <- terra::rast("lai.tif")
terra::crs(lai) #check crs of lai

plots <- readRDS("plots.rds")
sf::st_crs(plots) #check crs of sf

#Trial 1
plots_tr <- sf::as_Spatial(plots) #transform the sf and get the crs
lai_pr1 <- terra::project(lai, "+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs") #project the raster using the crs of the transformed sf
terra::plot(lai_pr1) #plot raster
plot(plots_tr, add=T, pch=19, col="black", cex=0.1) #overlay points

#Trial 2
lai_pr2 <- lai
terra::crs(lai_pr2) <- "+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" # replace lai crs
terra::plot(lai_pr2) #plot raster
plot(plots_tr, add=T, pch=19, col="black", cex=0.1) #overlay points

#Trial 3
lai_pr3 <- terra::project(lai, "epsg:25831") #project the raster using the EPSG code of the sf data (i.e., ETRS89 / UTM zone 31N)
terra::plot(lai_pr3) #plot raster
plot(plots_tr, add=T, pch=19, col="black", cex=0.1) #overlay points

Link to the data to run this example:
lai <- link removed
plots <- link removed
Maybe the issue is that the crs of the sf is WKT while the crs of the raster isn't? Also, using the sf without sf::as_Spatial() did not change the outcome. I also had a go at changing the crs of the sf with st_transform(). I read the many questions already posted on this but could not get the solution. Maybe spTransform()?
I hope this is not too silly. Many thanks.

?terra::project, you'll see it is advised that the 'y' in project(x, y be also a Spatrast, also be a SpatRast, so rasterize your 'sf', then use project. Will look a little closer, but that is the general idea. See Spacedman answer.

Seems to be the same problem as the other day when you had crs related problems with MODIS data. There is a shift between raster and vector data. GEE again? terra::crs(lai) <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"

Having fixed the coordinate reference system of your MODIS file, this is pretty straightforward making use of sf::st_transform() or terra::project(), depending on what crs you want to keep. For analysis, I'd continue with reprojecting vector data and keep the raster as-is, but feel free to get rid of the MODIS projection if you like (just don't forget about resampling). Also, absolutely no need to use {sp}.
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.8.2, PROJ 9.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

lai <- terra::rast("lai.tif")
plots <- readRDS("plots.rds")

# fix MODIS crs
modis_crs <- "+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs"
terra::crs(lai) <- modis_crs

# option 1: reproject vector data 
plots_reproj <- sf::st_transform(plots, modis_crs)

terra::plot(lai, main = "MODIS Sinusoidal")
plot(plots_reproj, add = TRUE, pch = 19, col="black", cex = 0.1)



# option 2: reproject raster data
lai_reproj <- terra::project(lai, "epsg:25831")

terra::plot(lai_reproj, main = "EPSG:25831")
plot(plots, add = TRUE, pch = 19, col="black", cex = 0.1)


Created on 2024-04-27 with reprex v2.1.0

Yes, my question was silly :). The thing is that this computation comes sequentially after the issue I had before. As that issue was solved, I thought the crs of MODIS was ok, so I am not sure why the MODIS crs got wrong again (but I could have checked). Makes sense? Does the crs get lost every time I do a computation? Anyway, thanks a lot for your further assistance. Do you also get the warning message after running sf::st_transform(plots, modis_crs)? Thanks!

Spatial attributes are preserved and should not be lost during computations etc. My guess is that you might haved fixed this for some SpatRaster object but things get messy and you probably proceed to work with another. Or maybe just overwrite your previous (fixed) object with one being imported from (unfixed) files again? Better check your code, this should not happen. Also, no warnings returned for me. What does it say?

Yeah, I will check my code again, thanks, as I agree with you that this should not happen. As per the warning, I get this:

Warning message:
In CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse, desired_accuracy,  :
GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: DatumEnsemble can only be exported to >WKT2:2019


@Fran, sometimes googling the 'obscure last parts of an error', here 'DatumEnsemble can only be exported to >WKT2:2019', can lead to clues StackOverflow leads to r-spatial sf and you can develop a diagnosis: Am I on Windows or Linux (Mac), what's my distribution, is my PROJ GDAL GEOS too old, quirks, bug fixes and the like. But it's the last, weird words that are both mostly unique and lead to interesting reading that helps.
